# Extending an SVG tooltip's hover zone out of its parent element's bounds

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a chart SVG that contains some elements that have tooltips attached. The tooltips are HTML embedded using `foreignObject` and are supposed to be shown when hovering on those elements. I gave the SVG `overflow: visible` to make sure tooltips could be fully displayed.

This works fine, but the problem is that as soon as the cursor leaves the bounds of the outer SVG, the tooltip disappears:

[image: SVG tooltip]

(The SVG ends just below the bottom axis)

Is there a way to "extend" the hover zone to include any element that sticks out of the SVG like this?

Comment: Don't use `overflow:visible`. Make the tooltip a html element outside the SVG `position: absolute` and use the SVG object position for the `top` and `left`. Please show your code to get a real solution.

Comment: The problem is that it becomes very hard to position the tooltips correctly if they're not children of the hover elements.

Comment: It's not very hard to position the tooltips correctly if they're not children of the hover. Please show some code. A minimal example would do.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how to an element outside the SVG as a tool tip:

```js
let mouse = {};
let tooltip = document.querySelector("#tooltip");
svg.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  tooltip.innerHTML = "";
  if (e.target.tagName == "circle") {
    mouse = oMousePos(svg, e);
   
    tooltip.innerHTML = e.target.id;
    tooltip.style.left = mouse.x + "px";
    tooltip.style.top = mouse.y + "px";
  }
});

function oMousePos(svg, evt) {
  var ClientRect = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    //objeto
    x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
    y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
  };
}
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid;}
circle{fill:gold;}
#tooltip{position:absolute;padding:1em; }
```

```html
<article>
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 100 50">
 <circle id="c1" cx="56" cy="17" r="15" />
 <circle id="c2" cx="23" cy="34" r="7" />
</svg>

<div id="tooltip"></div>
</article>
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm doing this in React and there's various constraints that make it hard to take out the tooltips. If it turns out I have to take them out I'll find a way, but for now it's not really what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I was given was to give the SVG a large 100px transparent `border-bottom` and `background-clip: padding-box` (although in my case that second part wasn't even necessary).

It's not perfect because it relies on a fixed border width and will break if a tooltip is taller than that, but it does extend the hover zone so it's one option.